# php Mostrar a variavel

Tags: php, variáveis

Tenho uma página que envia emails quando uma das datas do meu formulário estão a terminar.
Atualmente ele envia só o nome da pessoa que tem a data a terminar mas quero que ele informe a data que está no fim.

```
sql = ("SELECT Nome, data1, data2, data3, data4 < (now()+ interval 10 day)");
$validade = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($validade)){
$Nome = $row[0];
$PHPMailer = new PHPMailer(); 
(....)
$PHPMailer->Body = "<body><p><strong>Faltam 10 dias para terminar</strong> $Nome</body>";
```

Basta-me colocar as datas assim?

```
$data1 = $row[1];
$data2 = $row[2];(...)
```

Comment: teoricamente é so isso. Para saber as `chaves` do array, de um `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($validade)){ echo '<pre>'; print_r($row);}`

Comment: Você quer saber como encontrar a data que está para terminar ou como exibir a data?

Comment: quero apenas mostrar a data que está a terminar da pessoa $Nome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com o seu **select**, os índices equivalentes são:

- **0** equivalente a **Nome**
- **1** equivalente a **data1**
- **2** equivalente a **data2**
- **3** equivalente a **data3**
- **4** equivalente a **data4**

Supondo que a conexão com o banco já está estabelecida. O código seria:

```
sql = ("SELECT Nome, data1, data2, data3, data4 < (now()+ interval 10 day)");
$validade = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($validade))
{
    $nome = $row[0];
    $prazo = $row[1]; // Ou o índice da data que desejar acessar
    $mensagem = "<body><p><strong>Faltam menos de 10 dias para terminar $Nome.</strong></p>" .
                "<p>Prazo: $prazo</p></body>";

    $PHPMailer = new PHPMailer(); 
    (....)
    $PHPMailer->Body = $mensagem;
}
```

Se preferir usar o **nome dos campos** para capturar os dados, faça:

```
$nome = $row['Nome'];
$prazo = $row['data1']; // Ou o nome do campo da data que desejar acessar
```

Lembrando que quando utilizamos o **mysql_fetch_array** podemos passar um segundo parâmetro opcional, o **result_type** que podem ser as constantes **MYSQL_BOTH**, **MYSQL_NUM** ou **MYSQL_ASSOC**. Caso não informado, o valor usado por padrão pela função é o **MYSQL_BOTH**.

Exemplos de como viria o seu resultado (usei valores aleatórios):

```
// Usando MYSQL_BOTH
array (size=10)
    0 => string 'nome capturado' (length=14)
    1 => string '2013-12-20' (length=10)
    2 => string '2014-01-20' (length=10)
    3 => string '2014-02-20' (length=10)
    4 => string '2014-03-20' (length=10)
    'Nome'  => string 'nome capturado' (length=14)
    'data1' => string '2013-12-20' (length=10)
    'data2' => string '2014-01-20' (length=10)
    'data3' => string '2014-02-20' (length=10)
    'data4' => string '2014-03-20' (length=10)

// Usando MYSQL_NUM
array (size=10)
    0 => string 'nome capturado' (length=14)
    1 => string '2013-12-20' (length=10)
    2 => string '2014-01-20' (length=10)
    3 => string '2014-02-20' (length=10)
    4 => string '2014-03-20' (length=10)

// Usando MYSQL_ASSOC
array (size=10)
    'Nome'  => string 'nome capturado' (length=14)
    'data1' => string '2013-12-20' (length=10)
    'data2' => string '2014-01-20' (length=10)
    'data3' => string '2014-02-20' (length=10)
    'data4' => string '2014-03-20' (length=10)
```

Imagine que você retorne um valor alto de resultados, usando o padrão você duplica a quantidade de resultados armazenados na memória do servidor.

São essas pequenas coisas que influênciam no desempenho de seu script/aplicação.

Para otimizar mais o seu script, aconselho a usar [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) para fazer o acesso ao banco de dados. Para trabalhar com datas em PHP, use a classe [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.datetime.php) que possui diversas funções específicas para Data / Hora.

Answer (score 3):

Veja se isso pode solucionar seu problema.

```
sql = ("SELECT Nome, data1, data2, data3, data4 < (now()+ interval 10 day)");
$validade = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($validade)){
$Nome = $row[0];
$dataTermino = $row['data2']; // Ou a data que você deseja
$PHPMailer = new PHPMailer(); 
(....)
$PHPMailer->Body = "<body><p><strong>Faltam 10 dias para terminar</strong>$Nome</body>";
$PHPMailer->Body = "<body><p><strong>A data prevista é</strong>$dataTermino</body>";
```

Comment: $dataTermino = $row['data2']; 
Mas se eu tiver mais datas? coloco:
$dataTermino1 = $row['data3']; $dataTermino2 = $row['data4']; (...)

Comment: Ou pode colocar o `$row['data3']` direto na string. Não precisa ficar criando variáveis.