# Inserir consulta mysql dentro de uma variavel

Tags: php, mysql

Pessoal Estou fazendo um codigo para envio de email via phpmiler o problemas esta em como gerar um html como corpo do email contendo variáveis. Tipo

```
 Tipo arquivo html.php

 $variavel = "
 <html>...
 <body>...
 $cmd = "SELECT *FROM cotacao where c.cod = '12015172607'   ";      
  $produtos = mysql_query($cmd);
  $total = mysql_num_rows($produtos);
  while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {

  echo  $id_produtos = $linha['id_produtos'];

 </body>
 </html>
 ";
```

E tenho o codigo do phpmiler que pego esta $variaval

```
 include"html.php";// aonde esta a variavel
 $mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML

 $mail->Subject = $assunto;
 $mail->Body    = $variavel;  aqui recupero a variavel com o html
 $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
```

O Problema é como e fazer um SELECT do mysql  dentro de uma variaval

Comment: Creio que isso já está respondido aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5580/php-mostrar-a-variavel (Por se tratar de uma questão de conhecimento básico de MySQL e PHP, tem um monte de questões do site que mostram consultas MySQL sendo armazenadas em variáveis, sugeriria dar uma pesquisada no site pelas tags PHP e MySQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça a consulta primeiro depois chame ou substitua as variáveis no arquivo de template:

html.php

```
$cmd = "SELECT *FROM cotacao where c.cod = '12015172607'   ";      
$produtos = mysql_query($cmd);
$total = mysql_num_rows($produtos);

 $template = "
 <html>...
 <body>...
 Produtos: <br>"; 

while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {
   $template .=  $linha['id_produtos'] .'<br'>;
}

$template .= "</body></html>";
```